# How to make apache2 in front of tomcat

Tags: tomcat, apache2, virtualhost

I have a tomcat8 and an apache2 installed on my vps ( debian ), i want to know how to **redirect** *mydomain.com* to *mydomaine.com:8080/myproject* in order to frontating apache2 to tomcat.

I also want to know if it's possible to allow access to :8080 to only my apache ( only resquest from my localhost )

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty broad, but the short answer is that you need to configure Apache httpd as a "reverse proxy" for Tomcat. Read the documentation for `mod_proxy` for how to do that.

Ultimately, you are going to want to map your application's URI space (`/myapp`) over to Tomcat (`localhost:8080/myapp`) using something like this:

```
ProxyPass /myapp http://localhost:8080/myapp
ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://localhost:8080/myapp
```

Both lines are required for things like cookie-paths and redirects to work. *Do not* attempt to re-name the web application (e.g. from /myapp to /someotherapp).